# can a PWA have a user experience and appearance of a native app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I am considering starting to learn PWA as a mean to lunch a product to mobile devices. I know the current abilities of PWA but the concern about the UX and the feeling of the user.

as much as I check online and try to download different sites it all looks wrong.

1. the notification icon all have Chrome icon on them and look cheap and bizzar (android)
   [image]
2. the installed app logo have Chrome icon on the side
   [image]
3. Somehow it is possible apparently to download from the google play store but not the app store. didn't figure it out yet.It is called [TWA](https://medium.com/@firt/google-play-store-now-open-for-progressive-web-apps-ec6f3c6ff3cc). couldnt find a bottom line yet in that metter.
4. the installation is from the browser and is very new and weird for users

**are there any more differences I missed?
is there a workaround for some of that stuff?**

thanks for the help. Somehow I couldn't find this comparison online, which is undoubtedly a no go for developing a new project in PWA

Comment: If you see the chrome icon, that is most likely NOT an installed PWA, but a shortcut to a website. The user just selected the normal "Add to home screen" option available for every website.

Comment: You can't adjust native prompts like the banner you shared first. 
As far as your application's UX you can design it pretty much anyway you like. If you want to mimic a native style then go for it. I lean toward Material Design myself.
It is a matter of using CSS to drive most of the UI. Just because you see other create bad UI (and most native UIs are pretty bad) does not mean it cant be done in HTML/CSS.

Comment: I just confirmed that housing.com is not a Valid PWA with the lighthouse tool. So that shortcut is nothing more than a regular shortcut to a website. NOT an installed PWA.

Comment: that is a shame because they were one of the first examples Google promoted...

Comment: Thank you. I took Google first 5 examples and played with them.
Does someone have a good example of the PWA app?
and why aren't there many of them by now if it is possible?